# GPU memory allocation limit on Directx9/Windows 8

Tags: c++, textures, gpu, directx-9

I have simple DirectX 9.0c desktop application which load 10 huge textures (8192x8192 and 16384x16384).
I run in on ASUS GTX TITAN 12 GB.

On Windows 7 it runs ok and correctly allocates 7GB, but the same application on Windows 8.1 stops allocation texture memory at about 4GB.

1. Do you have any idea what could be a reason of this limit?
2. Are there any differences regarding to GPU memory allocation between Windows 7 and Windows 8?

Comment: Can you show us the code responsible for allocation? Which format do you use for these textures?

Comment: D3DXCreateTextureFromFileExW(g_pd3dDevice, stringtest, D3DX_DEFAULT_NONPOW2, D3DX_DEFAULT_NONPOW2, 1, 0, D3DFMT_UNKNOWN, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, D3DX_FILTER_BOX, D3DX_FILTER_BOX, 0, NULL, NULL, &g_pTexture[totalObjects])

Comment: What's the error you get? Is it a D3DERR_OUTOFVIDEOMEMORY?  Is it a 32 or 64 bit application?

Comment: Error: D3DERR_OUTOFVIDEOMEMORY. 64-bit application.

Comment: Update: On Win 8 I can allocate only about 4BG for textures but for vertex buffers I can allocate about 8GB.
Is that possible that driver have internal limits for data types (textures, buffers, etc)?

Comment: Have you tried making a DirectX 11 version of the same simple application?

Comment: Yes. DX 11 version works ok. And finally I'm going to migrate do DX 11. But for now, I have to find workaround for DX 9 version.

Comment: And it seems to be general problem of DX 9 and Wind 8. If you create any application, you can't allocate more than about 4 GB for textures.

Comment: If you are on a Windows 8 system, then just use DirectX 11. There's no scenario where you'd have to use Direct3D 9 for that. XPDM drivers are not installable on Windows 8, and all WDDM drivers support at least Feature Level 9.1 or later with DirectX 11.